# Using enums with AJV's "select/selectCases" keyword

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

Is it possible to give `select` a schema to match the case on?

The use case I have is that I want to select and match on a list of accepted values:

```js
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "addressCountry": {
      "type": ["string", "null"]
    }
  },
  "select": {
    "$data": "0/addressCountry"
  },
  "selectIf": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": ["FR", "JP", "US", "NZ", "DE"]
  },
  "selectThen": {
    "addressCountry": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: please note that `selectIf` and `selectThen` aren't keywords supported by AJV. It does support `selectCases` and `selectDefault`, however with `selectCases` you have to state each case individually. My question is more about if it's possible to match on multiple cases and use a single definition.

Comment: Can you direct me to the documentation for the ajv custom keywords `selectIf` and `selectThen` please? I can't find it.

Comment: Hiya @Relequestual, those keywords don't exist -- it's pseudo-code. I should have made that explicit.

The only supported keywords are `select`, `selectCases` and `selectDefault`. I want to match on multiple values for a definition within `selectCases`, rather than duplicate or set the same reference per matched value case. When I have 50 cases that it could match on, the schema gets a bit hefty.

Comment: I think what you want to do is wrap your logic in an `if/then` keyword set. Have you used `if` before and understand how it works with applicability of `then` and `else`?

Comment: Thanks for the snappy reply! Does `if/then` match on the data object itself and not on the schema? Or does it do both?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how `select` works. `if` works by, if the schema object value of `if` successfully validates, then the schema object value of `then` is applied, otherwise `else` is applied (if provided). See https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html for examples.

Comment: The AJV custom keyword `select` allows to select a value on the object AJV is validating by using the `{ "$data": "0/paramName" }`.

Answer (score 0):

@Relequestual managed to help me solve this outside of SO. I didn't need to use `select` at all, could just use `if/then/else` like so:

```js
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "contactByPost": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "streetAddress1": {
      "type": ["string", "null"]
    },
    "streetAddress2": {
      "type": ["string", "null"]
    },
    "streetAddress3": {
      "type": ["string", "null"]
    },
    "locality": {
      "type": ["string", "null"]
    },
    "region": {
      "type": ["string", "null"]
    },
    "postCode": {
      "type": ["string", "number", "null"]
    },
    "country": {
      "type": ["string", "null"]
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "contactByPost": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "const": true
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "if": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "country": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["JP", "US"]
        }
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "contactByPost": { "type": "boolean" },
        "streetAddress1": { "type": "string" },
        "locality": { "type": "string" },
        "region": { "type": "string" },
        "postCode": { "type": ["string", "number"] },
        "country": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["streetAddress1", "locality", "region", "postCode", "country"]
    },
    "else": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "contactByPost": { "type": "boolean" },
        "streetAddress1": { "type": "string" },
        "locality": { "type": "string" },
        "region": { "type": ["string", "null"] },
        "country": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["streetAddress1", "locality", "country"]
    }
  }
}
```

Would provide the following results:

```
// Valid
{
  "contactByPost": false
}

{
  "contactByPost": true,
  "streetAddress1": "123 Alphabet St",
  "streetAddress2": null,
  "streetAddress3": null,
  "locality": "City",
  "region": "State",
  "postCode": "12345",
  "country": "JP"
}

{
  "contactByPost": true,
  "streetAddress1": "123 Alphabet St",
  "streetAddress2": null,
  "streetAddress3": null,
  "locality": "City",
  "region": "State",
  "postCode": "12345",
  "country": "US"
}

{
  "contactByPost": true,
  "streetAddress1": "123 Alphabet St",
  "streetAddress2": null,
  "streetAddress3": null,
  "locality": "City",
  "region": "State",
  "postCode": "12345",
  "country": "NZ"
}

{
  "contactByPost": true,
  "streetAddress1": "123 Alphabet St",
  "streetAddress2": null,
  "streetAddress3": null,
  "locality": "City",
  "region": null,
  "postCode": null,
  "country": "NZ"
}

// Invalid
{
  "contactByPost": true
}

{
  "contactByPost": true,
  "streetAddress1": "123 Alphabet St",
  "streetAddress2": null,
  "streetAddress3": null,
  "locality": "City",
  "region": null,
  "postCode": null,
  "country": "JP"
}

{
  "contactByPost": true,
  "streetAddress1": "123 Alphabet St",
  "streetAddress2": null,
  "streetAddress3": null,
  "locality": "City",
  "region": null,
  "postCode": null,
  "country": "US"
}
```